# Android Custom shape using drawable

Tags: android, xml, drawable

I wanted to create a step custom step indicator. so I was looking for a way to create a custom shape maybe using drawable and set the text and color programatically. how can i make a custom shape like below:
[image]
Note: I want to change color of the element based on the completed and current and remaining steps programatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [vector drawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources.html) to define the shape.

You can use [tinting](https://developer.android.com/training/material/drawables.html) on vector drawables. Or a [ColorFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorFilter.html) for pre-lollipop devices